# /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ folder scripts can not be accessed from /var/www

Tags: python, html, apache, web, cgi-bin

I am studying HTML and CGI. I installed Apache on the ubuntu server, it works fine as I can see the test pages. I put a new webpage that calls a sample Hello world script from /usr/lib/cgi/ bin folder but when I run it I get this error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /usr/lib/cgi-bin/save_file.py was not found on this server.
```

Access rights for the /usr/lib/cgi-bin are all set to root:root and the permissions for the script are a+x.

The HTML file content is as following (taken from one of the samples online):

```
enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/usr/lib/cgi-bin/save_file.py" method="post"
```

(I had to remove HTML tags from here as they do not upload correctly but this is the relevant part)

Anybody has any idea why my script - `save_file.py` is not found?

Answer (score 0):

Use `action="/cgi-bin/save_file.py"` instead.

In the case of a URL, the root (`/`) is the root of your webserver, which is set up to be `/var/www`. It would be quite dangerous for your HTML pages to have access to your root directory, no? Imagine the consequences of allowing `action=/bin/rm`.

The default configuration of Apache automitically makes `/cgi-bin` point to `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`.

Comment: Hi David, tanks for your answer but It does not work as well. What happens is that it shows me the following error -  can not access /config/cgi-bin/save_file.py. So it seeks the file inside my current test website folder and not inside /usr/lib/cgi-bin...

Comment: Where is `/config/cgi-bin/save_file.py` coming from?

Comment: Make sure the action is `/cgi-bin/...` as opposed to `cgi-bin/...`.

Comment: I wrote some hello-world script. The message comes when I open the index.html that is located inside the subfolder of - /var/www/config/index.html in the browser.